# Prompt user to confirm row deletion

Tags: vba, excel

My users need the ability to delete rows.  They are comfortable right-clicking the row selector and choosing "Delete."  How can I add a prompt that users confirm that they'd like to delete a row?

[image]

Note that Worksheet_BeforeDelete() does not catch row deletions.

Comment: @Mic Sel, with that code I can catch the event but not Cancel it.  I may use that in conjunction with Application.Undo but I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: `Worksheet_BeforeDelete` doesn't work because the `Worksheet` class doesn't expose any such event (see object browser / F2). Why are you [re-asking the exact same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52121572/1188513)? The first one was *too broad*, how is this one any better? Handling `Worksheet_Change` was suggested in the comments of your previous post, have you tried it? If so, [edit] your post and include your code and describe what's not working and I'll be more than happy to retract my close vote.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, first - thanks for trying to help me be smarter here.  I'm trying, but I don't see what's too broad about this question.  I'm trying to laser-pinpoint what I need, while also posting it in a way that will be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: You can customize the menu you see on right click.   Just replace the delete button to call your own sub that includes the required prompt. [See here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win001.htm)

Comment: Thanks for not lashing out at me for being a "mean unhelpful power-tripping close-voting jerk"! Meta Q&A [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513) does a better job at explaining this than I ever could =)

Comment: @chris neilsen, I hadn't thought about approaching it from this angle.  I will try this.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, on the contrary, I think that once I fully understand what you are suggesting I will be a better member here. Thanks.

Comment: You have no idea how I wish *everyone* came here with this awesome mindset!!

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, I closed the loop on this post by adding the solution, which I cobbled together from chris neilsen's suggestion and some other ideas.  Thanks again for your tips.

Comment: @JohnJoseph are you interested in a way of doing it with the built-in Delete option? Also, should it work across the whole workbook or just select sheets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution adds a "Delete Row" custom menu item to the Row context menu.  It looks like this when the row selector is right-clicked.  It prompts the user to confirm the row deletion before actually deleting the row...

[image: Confirmation message]

In a project-level module, add the following subroutine...

```
Public Sub DeleteRow()

    If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbOkCancel, "Confirm Delete") = vbOk Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

In the worksheet code module, add the following subroutines...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    'reset to standard context menu before adding new option
    Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset

    'add custom row deletion call
    With Application.CommandBars("Row").Controls.Add
        .Caption = "Delete Row"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "DeleteRow"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    'get rid of the customization when you're done with this sheet
    Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset

End Sub
```

Comment: Well done! Note that you can also *remove* the commandbar button for the default "Delete" context command - which is otherwise still available =) also.. (a mere nitpick) - I'd go with `vbYesNo` for the prompt instead of `vbOkCancel`, and maybe use `vbExclamation` (or not - users love to ignore warnings!)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I think `vbQuestion` is also a nice alternative, and yes the OP should definitely use `vbYesNo` for this case.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed `vbQuestion` is ambiguous UX and actively discouraged though ;-)

Comment: Oh really? Didn't know that. I don't know much about UX tbh. Would appreciate if you have a link to an article/post that elaborates on this.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Never mind, I found a nice explanation in the .NET's [`MessageBoxIcon`Enum documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon). Wow! I've been using it for a long time and never thought it was a bad choice lol. Thanks for this information!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you *can* reuse the existing Delete option with nearly the same method.

In the Sheet module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim c As CommandBarButton
    For Each c In Application.CommandBars("row").Controls
        If c.Caption = "&Delete" Then
            c.OnAction = "delete_row"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set right_click_target = Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Dim c As CommandBarButton
    For Each c In Application.CommandBars("row").Controls
        If c.Caption = "&Delete" Then
            c.OnAction = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And in your standalone module:

```
Option Explicit

Public right_click_target As Range

Public Sub delete_row()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", vbYesNo, "Deletion") = vbYes Then
        right_click_target.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```